# Create Unique Table

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table with duplicates in a identifying field. In the other columns, values differ when the identifying field duplicates. I want to select the values of the other columns that make it to a new, distinct, table of the identifying field.

I cannot make the table have the count of the distinct selection of the identifying field.

XX_DDD1 = Distinct identifying field table

POLY_NUMS_FOR_CC_TYPES_V1 = Source table

XX_DD2 = Duplicate Poly_nums

```
Create table XX_DDD as select
a.Poly_num,
 (CASE WHEN a.poly_num in (select poly_num from XX_DD2) THEN 
        (CASE WHEN b.Status = 'Planned' and b.Ownership = 'David' THEN 'Planned'

              WHEN b.Status = 'Planned' and b.Ownership = 'Peter' THEN 'Planned'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'David' THEN 'Deferral'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'Peter' THEN 'Deferral'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'John' THEN 'Deferral'
        END)
        ELSE b.Status
  END) Status,
  (CASE WHEN a.poly_num in (select poly_num from XX_DD2 ) THEN 
        (CASE WHEN b.Status = 'Planned' and b.Ownership = 'David' THEN 'David'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Planned' and b.Ownership = 'Peter' THEN 'Peter'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'David' THEN 'David'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'Peter' THEN 'Peter'
              WHEN b.Status = 'Deferral' and b.Ownership = 'John' THEN 'John'
        END)
        ELSE b.Ownership
  END) Ownership
  from POLY_NUMS_FOR_CC_TYPES_V1 b, XX_DDD1 a where a. poly_num = b.poly_num ;
```

Comment: Is the query working?

Comment: Its working but the count of records equals that of the table with the duplicates POLY_NUMS_FOR_CC_TYPES_V1 = 14104, XX_DDD = 14104. XX_DDD should equal the number of records in xx_DDD1 (11379)

Comment: I notice that your two top-level CASE statements are the same.  Could you have meant "not in" in the second one?

Comment: I can change that case statement all I want and it won't effect the number of records supposed to make it to the table. But, no, I want it as 'IN'. thx